# Dynamic ROC curve plot

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, bokeh

I'm trying to plot a ROC curve with a dinamic plot, where as I change the True Positives (TP), True Negatives (TN), False Positives (FP), and False Negatives (FN), the ROC curve changes accordingly. However, I'm struggling with connecting the math with the `CustomJS` function. The plot I have is based on the [slider.py](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html) bokeh example:

```
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
import bokeh.io
bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)
import numpy as np
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, show

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(y_range=(-10, 10), width=400, height=400)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

TP_slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, value=40, step=1, title="TP")
TN_slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, value=40, step=1, title="TN")
FP_slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, value=10, step=1, title="FP")
FN_slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, value=10, step=1, title="FN")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, TP=TP_slider, TN=TN_slider, FP=FP_slider, FN=FN_slider),
                    code="""
    const data = source.data;
    const A = TP.value;
    const k = TN.value;
    const phi = FP.value;
    const B = FN.value;
    const x = data['x']
    const y = data['y']
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i] = B + A*Math.sin(k*x[i]+phi);
    }

    source.change.emit();
""")

TP_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
TN_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
FP_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
FN_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = row(
    plot,
    column(TP_slider, TN_slider, FP_slider, FN_slider),
)

show(layout)
```

[image]

An example of the ROC curve I'm using (it's a reproducible example):

```
#############################
### SET-UP DATA AND MODEL ###
#############################
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
import xgboost
import lightgbm
import graphviz
import shap
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, 
                    n_features=10,
                    n_informative=3, 
                    n_redundant=5, 
                    n_repeated=0, 
                    n_classes=2,
                    n_clusters_per_class=2, 
                    weights=None, 
                    flip_y=0.01, 
                    class_sep=1.0, 
                    hypercube=True, 
                    shift=0.0, 
                    scale=1.0, 
                    shuffle=False, 
                    random_state=42)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
df.columns = 'X' + (df.columns+1).astype(str)
df[df.columns[-3:]] = df[df.columns[-3:]].astype(int)
df['Y'] = y


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop('Y', axis=1), df['Y'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


n_negative_class = y_train.value_counts().sort_index()[0]
n_positive_class = y_train.value_counts().sort_index()[1]

xgb = xgboost.XGBClassifier(random_state = 42, n_estimators=10, max_depth=3,
                    scale_pos_weight = n_negative_class/n_positive_class, 
                    use_label_encoder=False)

xgb.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_train,y_train),(X_test, y_test)], eval_metric=["auc", 'logloss'])
y_train_scores = xgb.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]

######################
### ROC CURVE PLOT ###
######################
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_train, xgb.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1])
roc_auc = dict()
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

# Plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.5,7.5))

#fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(fpr, tpr, label=f'Train = {roc_auc.round(4)}', c= '#1f77b4')
ax1.set_title('Plot 1')

ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
ax1.grid(True)

ax1.legend(loc="lower right", shadow=True, fancybox=True)

ax1.set_ylabel('True Positive Rate')
ax1.set_xlabel('False Positive Rate')

ax1.set_xlim([-0.05, 1.0])
ax1.set_ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The output expected would be the plot of the ROC curve with the sliders. However, I'm open to changes or better approaches you can imagine or do. The only requisite is the ROC curve has to be dependent on actions of the user, like (for example) moving the TP, TN, FP, and FN quantity.

The final objective of this plot, is to show how the ROC curve changes given different model performances.

Comment: TP, TN, FP and FN would only define a single point upon a ROC curve, and we wouldn't even know which one, since no thresholds or scores are specified.
ROC curve is parametric, recalculating TPR and FPR for every possible classification threshold based upon model scores (`predict_proba()`). Only changing those scores would affect it.

Comment: predict_proba>= 0.5 shows the desired predicted class (as far as I remember). It is possible, based on this, to create a fictitious predict_proba array, with the desired tp, if I'm not mistaken.